# Wiegand 34 readers vs MFRC522. Different card Uid

Tags: arduino, nfc, wiegand

On arduino, one mifare card, was different UID.
Read with mfrc522: 30166134113 (DEC)
with Wiegang 34: 1904649758 (DEC)
Possible convert UID from Wiegang 34, to mfrc522 code ?

Comment: Please supply the exact make and model of the mifare card as some have 4 byte UID's and some 7 byte and some have both 4 and 7 byte. Also don't convert these to decimal, give each byte as Hex pair as sometimes the way they are converted is wrong. I have seen some readers return the UID data in the reverse order and this makes a big difference to the decimal conversion especially as Mifare cards usually the first byte is `04` in Hex

Comment: #facepalm Yes, this reverse byte order. Wiegand 34 - 7186A61E mfrc522 - 1EA68671

Answer (score 0):

So the answer it seems is that some readers return the bytes in the reverse order which causes the decimal conversion to be vastly different.